# Regular Expressions pattern with Special characters

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I'm working on a regular expressions pattern, but it contains a number of special characters. I'm not really sure how to incorporate them in a normal regex pattern string.  Specifically, I need to test to see if a string contains '+/-'...

I've tried using quotes etc but have no luck (I'm extremely new to regex).  I am coding this in C# 4.0.

One string example is "3Z1Z +/- 5.5"

Any help is much appreciated - Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a simple regex :

```
foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(SubjectString, @"\+/-");
```

Will return true if this sequence of characters is found anywhere in your string. The explanation is left as an exercise to you.

Read more **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)**.

Answer (score 1):

These are part of the [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) list (*[see also](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)*). Basically, add them to the pattern by prefixing them with a backslash (`\`). e.g. `+` becomes `\+`

```
^\+|\-$     # + or -
```

The same would go for anything else with special meaning, such as `.`, `{`, `}`, `(`, `)`, `^`, `$`, `|`, `[`, `]`, etc.

There are some exceptions though. For instance, when creating a class such as: `[a-z]` the hyphen (`-`) would have special meaning (all letters from a through z). So if you wanted a literal hyphen you'd have to escape it (unless it falls as the last character of the class). e.g.

```
[a-z-A-Z]      # hyphen should be escaped if you wanted a literal hyphen
[a-z\-A-Z]     # the "correct" counter-part

[a-zA-Z-]      # actually legal because it's inserted as the last character
               # and therefor treated as a literal hyphen despite not being
               # escaped.
```